# How to integrate a loop into my code that will apply my request to every filterViewId?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Currently encountering two problems with my code after executing:

```
API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. 
Unknown name "fields" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field. 
Invalid value at 'requests[0].update_filter_view.filter.filter_view_id' (TYPE_INT32), "*" (line 27, file "macros")
```

The first problem is that my request is not recognizing "fields" - I don't know why this is happening.

The second issue, and the main reason for posting this is that filterViewId is looking for an integer when all I have referenced was "*" as a method to update all filter views in the sheet. How can I integrate a loop into my code so that it Gets the first filterViewId and applies the request and then moves on to the next?

```
function UpdateFilterView() {
    var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();  
    for each (var dataSheet in sheets){ 
      var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
      var sheetId = dataSheet.getSheetId();
      var filterSettings = {
        "filterViewId": "*",
        "range":{
        "sheetId": sheetId,
        "startRowIndex": 0,
        "endRowIndex": lastRow,
        "startColumnIndex": 0,
        "endColumnIndex": lastColumn
        }
       }
      };


var requests = [{
  "fields": "*",
  "updateFilterView":{
  "filter": filterSettings
  }
 }];

 Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests":requests},sheetId);

 }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. In your script, it seems that the for loop doesn't work. Do you want to use the values of the sheet of the last index? 2. About `How can I integrate a loop into my code so that it Gets the first filterViewId and applies the request and then moves on to the next?`, what meaning of `the first filterViewId` is?

Comment: @Tanaike - 1. Yes, I would like to use to use both the first row/column index and last row/column index for the filtered range on each filter view, so for example, the Filtered Range is A1:AS1453, Start Row/Column Index should be 0, and end row/end column should be lastRow/lastColumn. 

2. This might be hard to describe, but the filterViewID is an integer that is assigned to each filter view on a specific worksheet of a google spreadsheet. When you select a filterView on a sheet, this param is passed in the url at the end like so  '&fvid=##########'

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to reflect one condition of the filterView to all filterViews. I could understand like this. And all filterView IDs can be retrieved. From this, you want to retrieve the condition from one filterView and want to update all other filterViews with the retrieved filterView condition. Is my understanding correct? I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your request is not recognizing `fields`, because `fields` needs to go inside of `"updateFilterView":{...}` as you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatefilterviewrequest).
2. If your filter Ids are incrementing with the sheet numbers (e.g. `"filterViewId": 1` for the first sheet, `"filterViewId": 2` for the second sheet etc.0, you can assign  `filterview` to a counter variable which increments during each loop iteration.

Example:

```
var i=0;
for each (var dataSheet in sheets){ 
  i++;
  ...
  var filterSettings = {
     "filterViewId": i,
        ...
```

Alternatively, you can also replace the `for each` loop by a `for(var i=1; i<=sheet.length;i++)` loop - then you iterate through `sheets` and `filterview` simultanously.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to correct the fields part after posting, but the problem is that the filterViewId does not incremement by 1.
This may be helpful, If I am on Sheet 1 , and in a filter there are two variables passed in the url that should be retreivable, GID (sheet ID) and FVID (filter view ID) `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*SpreadsheetID*/edit#*gid=1912501544&fvid=1532254743*` I would assume that there is a way to retreive fvid the same way we can retrieve sheetIds but if not could I just store each fvid by sheet in an array?

Comment: You can get the FVIDs with getFilterViewId() and push each one as an element into an array. When you update your filter views with a loop you can iterate over the array elements:  "filterViewId": myArray[i]